# Put xml node's full path in attribute file and read the node's value from main xsl file in xsl fo

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, pdf-generation

I have been using fop 0.95 to generate pdf files from xml data. I have three files involved in the process: test.xml, test.xsl and attributes.xsl. Naturally I have xml data in xml file. Here test.xml is the main xsl file which imports attribute sets from attributes.xsl file. For example, I have following entries in the attributes.xsl file:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="headerTable" foa:class="table">
    <xsl:attribute name="table-layout">fixed</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="width">6.05in</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">left</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="white-space-collapse">false</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

Now my requirement is to place the attribute name in attribute file and store the associated values in the xml file. This way:

```
<MyRoot>
   <tableHeader>
      <tableLayout>fixed</tableLayout>
      <width>6.05in</width>
      <textAlign>left</textAlign>
      <whiteSpaceCollapse>false</whiteSpaceCollapse>
   </tableHeader>
</MyRoot>
```

After this I will have the attribute file as follows:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="headerTable" foa:class="table">
   <xsl:attribute name="table-layout">MyRoot/tableHeader/tableLayout</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="width">MyRoot/tableHeader/width</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="text-align">MyRoot/tableHeader/textAlign</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="white-space-collapse">MyRoot/tableHeader/whiteSpaceCollapse</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

As usual I use the attribute from the main xsl file as follows:

```
<fo:table xsl:use-attribute-sets="headerTable">
   <fo:table-column column-width="3in"></fo:table-column>
   <fo:table-column column-width="3.5in"></fo:table-column>
   <fo:table-body>
      <!--table rows and cells goes here-->             
   </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

While executing, I get the following error:

```
"Ignoring property: table-layout="MyRoot/tableHeader/tableLayout" <Illegal character; property:'table-layout'>"
```

Has anyone any idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wandering in various websites and getting no response in the question here, I had hard times with the problem. While thinking upon the problem and performing hit and trial, I just got to put this line:

```
<xsl:attribute name="width">
     <xsl:value-of select="MyRoot/tableHeader/width">
     </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:attribute>
```

instead of the following  in the attribute file:

```
<xsl:attribute name="width">MyRoot/tableHeader/width</xsl:attribute>
```

And I did same for all those xml node path placed in the attribute file. This worked awsome! Thanks.